# Who commented on my post?

Tags: feature-request, comments, global-inbox

We can see here that I have comments / answers / edits and edit suggestions. It is nice that it shows that, but it does not show the person who commented / answered etc.

[image]

It would be nice to know who it was because that could help me keep track of discussions etc - for example, maybe I don't want to reply to a certain discussion right now, and so I don't want to mark the comment as "read" (change the link colour).

Comment: *I don't want to mark the comment as "read".* - once you click your inbox indicator, you'll mark it as "read" anyway.

Comment: No, I mean the non clicked link colour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've made a userscript to do this.

> [image]

It will add the author's name at the top of the notification by looking at the type, and using the Stack Exchange API to get the information.

Caveats:

- It only adds the name for the first 15 items (after all, we are using the API!)
- It only works for answers, comments, and edit suggestions (but these are the main ones, I think!)

### You can install it from [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/5d8296e9e3eb2a246f70/raw/2f334f402cb609cefb194f990222a20e10acc293/addAuthorNameInInbox.user.js) :)

I've also added it to the development version (v1.7) of my [SE Additional Optional Features Userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Add author name to inbox notifications
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Adds the author's name for comments, answers, and edits in the topbar inbox dialog
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        var length = mutation.addedNodes.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var $addedNode = $(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
            if (!$addedNode.hasClass('inbox-dialog')) {
                return;
            }

            for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) { //first 15 items
                getAuthor($addedNode.find('.inbox-item').eq(x));
            }
        }
    });
}).observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    attributes: true,
    subtree: true
});

var getFromAPI = {
    'comment': function (d) {
        var comment_id = d.link.split('/')[5].split('?')[0];
        $.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/" + comment_id + "?order=desc&sort=creation&site=" + d.sitename, function (json) {
            d.n.find('.item-header .item-type').text(d.n.find('.item-header .item-type').text() + ' (' + json.items[0].owner.display_name + ')');
        });
    },
    'answer': function (d) {
        var answer_id = d.link.split('/')[4].split('?')[0];
        $.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answer_id + "?order=desc&sort=creation&site=" + d.sitename, function (json) {
            d.n.find('.item-header .item-type').text(d.n.find('.item-header .item-type').text() + ' (' + json.items[0].owner.display_name + ')');
        });
    },
    'edit suggested': function (d) {
        var edit_id = d.link.split('/')[4];
        $.getJSON("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/suggested-edits/" + edit_id + "?order=desc&sort=creation&site=" + d.sitename, function (json) {
            d.n.find('.item-header .item-type').text(d.n.find('.item-header .item-type').text() + ' (' + json.items[0].proposing_user.display_name + ')');
        });
    },
    'other': function (d) {
        console.log('Script does not currently support getting author information for type "' + d.n.find('.item-header .item-type').text() + '"!');
    }
};

function getAuthor($node) {
    var type = $node.find('.item-header .item-type').text();
    (getFromAPI[type] || getFromAPI['other'])({
        n: $node,
        link: $node.find('a').eq(0).attr('href'),
        sitename: $node.find('a').eq(0).attr('href').split('/')[2].split('.')[0]
    });
}
```

---

However, it would be *much* better if this was implemented by default, because then *all* possible types could be covered!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, seeing the username in the dropdown would help with understanding the context of the comment and its relative importance. If it's the fourth comment from the same help vampire on my answer, then I'm definitely not clicking through to it... but it could also be another user commenting on the same post.

Also, this functionality already exists for chat replies. Expanding it to comments (and answers) would make the dropdown appearance more consistent.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As for me, I don't care who (s)he was. If someone want to request clarification or more info on my post, I'll provide it. Why does the commenter matter *in this case*? Do you hate some users?

Anyway, if you really want to know all the commenters on your posts, go to [responses > comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=comments) (personally I almost never look there, unless the numbers are quite disturbing). The inbox indicator in the top bar provides you with the most essential info.

Comment: No, but I have multiple similar conversations on [ubuntu.se]. Sometimes, I am quite tired of trying to explain to certain people so I want a break.

Comment: @Tim Tell the person once that you are tired and need a little break cuz he just doesn't want to understand what your explanations, and leave him on this point.

Comment: @nicael And then another comment appears on that post, which may or may not be from a different user whom you don't want to ignore...